# Why can I not issue the same query against a recursive view as I can on the table backing it?

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have a `tags` table, and on it I have defined a view from a recursive CTE, containing all the columns of the tags table:

```sql
CREATE VIEW tags_paths AS
WITH RECURSIVE tag_path (id, created_at, updated_at, community_id, tag_set_id, wiki_markdown,
                         wiki, excerpt, parent_id, name, path) AS
                   (
                       SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, community_id, tag_set_id, wiki_markdown,
                              wiki, excerpt, parent_id, name, name as path
                       FROM tags
                       WHERE parent_id IS NULL
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT t.id, t.created_at, t.updated_at, t.community_id, t.tag_set_id,
                              t.wiki_markdown, t.wiki, t.excerpt, t.parent_id, t.name,
                              concat(tp.name, ' > ', t.name) as path
                       FROM tag_path AS tp JOIN tags AS t ON tp.id = t.parent_id
                   )
SELECT * FROM tag_path
ORDER BY path;
```

I can issue this query against the `tags` table just fine:

```sql
SELECT  tags.*, COUNT(posts.id) AS post_count
FROM `tags`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts_tags` ON `posts_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`community_id` = 2 AND `posts`.`id` = `posts_tags`.`post_id`
WHERE `tags`.`community_id` = 2 AND `tags`.`tag_set_id` = 3
GROUP BY tags.id ORDER BY COUNT(posts.id) DESC LIMIT 96 OFFSET 0;
```

However, the equivalent query issued against the `tags_paths` view:

```sql
SELECT  tags_paths.*, COUNT(posts.id) AS post_count
FROM `tags_paths`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts_tags` ON `posts_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags_paths`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`community_id` = 2 AND `posts`.`id` = `posts_tags`.`post_id`
WHERE `tags_paths`.`community_id` = 2 AND `tags_paths`.`tag_set_id` = 3
GROUP BY tags_paths.id ORDER BY COUNT(posts.id) DESC LIMIT 96 OFFSET 0;
```

comes back as an error, specifically:

```
[42000][1055] Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
'tags_paths.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Why? What can I do about it?

Comment: `tags.id` is primary key (more precisely - unique and not NULL is enough) whereas `tags_paths.id` is not. PS. Forget about asterisk as "all columns" - except `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Is there a way around that, @Akina?

Comment: Replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT {columns list}` and expand `GROUP BY` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Akina states `id` is a key on the table `tags`, but not on the view. Therefore, a direct dependency cannot be established in the view for the rest of the columns against the `id` column, as specified by the SQL Standard.

You have two options. You can either:

1. Add all columns to the `GROUP BY` clause. Sometimes this is not possible for large types such as `TEXT` or binaries.
2. Or, you can aggregate the columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Below is the modified SQL statement using the latter:

```
SELECT
  tags_paths.id,
  max(tags_paths.created_at) as created_at,   
  max(tags_paths.updated_at) as updated_at, 
  max(tags_paths.community_id) as community_id, 
  max(tags_paths.tag_set_id) as tag_set_id, 
  max(tags_paths.wiki_markdown) as markdown,
  max(tags_paths.wiki) as wiki, 
  max(tags_paths.excerpt) as excerpt, 
  max(tags_paths.parent_id) as parent_id, 
  max(tags_paths.name) as name, 
  max(tags_paths.path) as path,
  COUNT(posts.id) AS post_count
FROM `tags_paths`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts_tags` ON `posts_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags_paths`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`community_id` = 2 
                       AND `posts`.`id` = `posts_tags`.`post_id`
WHERE `tags_paths`.`community_id` = 2 AND `tags_paths`.`tag_set_id` = 3
GROUP BY tags_paths.id 
ORDER BY COUNT(posts.id) DESC 
LIMIT 96 
OFFSET 0;
```

Yep, it becomes longer.